# ie8 issue with qtip2

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, qtip2

I am getting  'Object doesn't support this property or method' error in ie8.

While debugging I found that I am getting error on 1st line below

```
tooltip = d("<div/>", {
  id: this._id,
  ...
}).toggleClass
```

when I print `'d'`, it's value is  `'function(e,t){return new ...}'`

Answer (score 0):

IE8 seems to have a problem with the `tooltip` global variable that qTip uses (maybe because of strict-mode?) such that any reference to it causes the exception.  Try declaring the variable explicitly in your main JS file first:

`var tooltip = tooltip || null;`